# Cannot create measure or calculated column in Power BI

Tags: ssas, powerbi

I am working on Power BI with a SSAS instance. I am using a direct connection to browse the data. I need to build custom measures and columns to create a dashboard, but the buttons are greyed out and the right-click menu on a table does not show 'New mesure' or 'New column'.

Obviously I am missing something, any idea what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't create measure or column if you are connected to SSAS

> Question: If I created a live connection, can I edit the model or query in Power BI Desktop?
>
> Answer: No. All of the query and modeling features in Power BI Desktop
>   are disabled when exploring live data.

you can found other info here : https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-analysis-services-tabular-data/